# How to use RxUI interactions in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui, reactivex

I'm trying to figure out this interaction thing in WPF. I had an issue a while back and had mentioned that I used a command to invoke Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog. In the course of helping me through my actual issue, it was suggested to me that I use an interaction, I'm assuming in lieu of a command, to invoke the OpenFileDialog, but it worked at the time so I just put it off until now. I have read through https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/interactions/ and I think I understand, kind of, how to create the interaction and register the handle, I just can't figure out how to invoke the interaction, like on a button press. Can someone give me an example or point me to an already published one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally I would have a Command like

```cs
public static class CommonInteractions
{
   public static Interaction<string, string> SelectFile { get; } = new Interaction<string, string>();
}

public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
   private string _fileContents;
   public MyViewModel()
   {
      OpenFile = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async _ => await OpenNiceFile());
   }

   public async Task OpenNiceFile()
   {
      var fileName = await CommonInteractions.SelectFile.Handle("Please Select a Nice File");

      if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(fileName) || !File.Exists(fileName)) return;

      FileContents = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
   }

   public string FileContents
   {
      get => _fileContents;
      set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _fileContents, value);
   }
   
   ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> OpenFile { get; }
}

public class MainWindow
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
      CommonInteractions.SelectFile.RegisterHandle(async interaction =>
      {
         var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog()
         {
            FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
            DefaultExt = ".txt"; // Default file extension
            Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension
            Title = interaction.Input;
         };

         // Show open file dialog box
         Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

         // Process open file dialog box results
         if (result == true)
         {
            // Open document
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
            interaction.SetOutput(filename);
         }
         else 
         {
            interaction.SetOutput(null);
         }
      });
   }
}
```

So in this example I have a static interaction. You can either have a interaction per view/view model, or in this case I globally register a file handle for the entire application.

I then will register a interaction handler, which will invoke your open file dialog.

On the ViewModel side I request a file name, if null I don't do anything, otherwise open the file contents.

Comment: So how is this better than just invoking the dialog right inside a command? Also, thank you for the great response.

Comment: Mainly you don't have your view models knowing how file dialogs work. Eg it's common in RxUI to have Windows/Xamarin Android/Xamarin iOS targets, and each has slightly different file dialogs. Also useful for testing, eg you can simulate in a test just returning a dummy file name.

Comment: Also another possible benefit, in the example above, you only register how a file open dialog works once (you could change the input to have file type or something). If you were opening in different view models file dialogs commonly it can simplify your open code a lot.

Comment: I am getting a ```System.NullReferenceException``` at ```CommonInteractions.SelectFile.RegisterHandle```

Comment: Nvm, its because ```public static Interaction<string, string> SelectFile { get; }``` never got set, I changed it to ```public static Interaction<string, string> SelectFile { get; } = new Interaction<string, string>();```. Now it compiles fine but the ```OpenFileDialog``` never shows. I have to see if I can figure that out now.

Comment: I got it working. I edited your answer to reflect the changes I made; commenting out what you had and adding my changes. would you mind looking at it and letting me know if the changes are appropriate. It works, but I am still a pretty novice programmer and am not sure if the changes I made were the "correct" ones. Thank you again for the help.